# The body of my HTTPClient Post Message does not work to my server

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I try to send REST Post request thanks to the following code (in Xamarin) :

```
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestURI))
            {
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", app.OAuth_Token);
                string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(OrderedItem);
                if (content != null)
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }

                response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
```

The message is well catch by the server. But the body is null... 
Here it is the string content -->

```
"{\"ItemId\":5,\"Quantity\":1,\"SelectedSize\":null,\"SelectedSalt\":false,\"SelectedHotNotCold\":false,\"SelectedMeatId\":null,\"SelectedSauceId\":null}"
```

The server is working on a ASP.Net Web.api the follosing way:

```
            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return BadRequest("Body cannot be null");

... some code 
}
```

Strangely I tested the request with Postman and everything is working well...

EDIT

By changing the header the following way I can get the message content:

```
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return BadRequest("Body cannot be null");
    ... other code 
    }
```

And the content of object is the following:

```
{{  "ItemId": 4,  "Quantity": 1,  "SelectedSize": null,  "SelectedSalt": alse,  "SelectedHotNotCold": false,  "SelectedMeatId": null,  "SelectedSauceId": null}}
```

So I have the feeling the Content from my HttpRequest has been modified somewhere on the path... There is two new outer brackets that came...

Comment: Did your postman request have the `Content-Type: application/json` header?

Comment: @JessedeWit Yes it has.

Comment: And you are sure that `string content` is not `null`?

Comment: @JessedeWit Yes... Indeed I even stop the code there and copy the content and past it in Postman to make sure there is no mistake in the way to serialize the Json... And it is working from Postman but not from the app...

Comment: Could you add the `string` from the `content` to the question?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov I updated the post. You can have a look.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this `FromBody` with a `string` parameter when the input string is actually a json object. I have to explicitly use `[FromBody] dynamic value` or use a model class. Using a string, I get 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.'. Did you surround your request in postman with quotes?

Comment: @JessedeWit Yes in PostMan I have kept the surrounding quotes... And this sounds to be a part of the explaination... 
If I remove the quotes in Postman I have well the same issue as my HttpRequest. 
But now if I try with [FromBody] dynamic value. The value is still null... 
Sounds like ASP.Net WebApi framework does not bind correctly depending on format?

Comment: Did you remove the backslashes from your postman request that escape the inner quotes? I sincerely expect your api to throw some kind of exception here instead of passing a null value to your controller.

Comment: @JessedeWit No. Just removed the first and the last one while keeping the brackets...

Comment: In that case you'll have invalid json in your postman request. Make sure the json is valid using [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) for example and see what happens. Note that we're currently trying to fix your postman request, your application request may be 'fixed' already.

Comment: @JessedeWit I think the Json string and Postman are both ok. Meaning if I use the generated Json above with the external quotes with postman. It works.
This make me feel that the HTTPRequest is changing something in the content (may be removing the quotes) that makes the things wrong at the end

Comment: Json content is not supposed to be surrounded by quotes. So your application request is correct, but your postman request is not. Remove all backslashes from your postman request, and use dynamic (or model) type in your server. I suppose that would work. Also, I suppose your client code will work using dynamic type on your server.

Comment: @JessedeWit I tested the JSon string (with the quote) witht he tool you provided jsonlint and it sounds to be valide. 
Strangely I have other Get request from my server. And the string I receive from the server in my app does have also the quotes... Which is well interpreted by my JSon deserializer. 
I tried to tried Dynamic and Model types... But in both case I still get a null object...

Comment: @JessedeWit please see my EDIT where I could force to get the details from received Post Request

Comment: That is just an escape character in a string. The double brace is an escape for a single brace. See [Escaping Braces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#escaping-braces). If you'd write that string to the console, you'd get valid json. Seems like this is working fine now. Perhaps you should delete your question, and ask a new one with specifics if you run into something else, because this comment thread is exploding.